# Проблема с Java VK API. Access denied (15): Access denied: no access to call this method

Tags: java, vkontakte-api

Создал свою Standalone приложение. Получаю токен от VK с помощью [ScribeJava](https://github.com/scribejava/scribejava)

Все получено, все хорошо. Но, при попытке вывода тестовой публикации на стену - возникает ошибка:

```
com.vk.api.sdk.exceptions.ApiAccessException: Access denied (15): Access denied: no access to call this method
at com.vk.api.sdk.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.parseException(ExceptionMapper.java:37)
at com.vk.api.sdk.client.ApiRequest.execute(ApiRequest.java:73)
at com.killersssurprise.SocialMedia.VkontakteExample.main(VkontakteExample.java:122)
```

Сам код имеет вид:

```
 public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    // Replace these with your client id and secret
    final String clientId = "ID приложения";
    final String clientSecret = "Секретный код приложения";
    final String secretState = "secret" + new Random().nextInt(999_999);
    final OAuth20Service service = new ServiceBuilder()
            .apiKey(clientId)
            .apiSecret(clientSecret)
            .state(secretState)
            .scope("wall,offline") // разрешения на действия со стеной и постоянный доступ
            .callback("https://google.com.ua/")
            .build(VkontakteApi.instance());
    final Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("=== " + NETWORK_NAME + "'s OAuth Workflow ===");
    System.out.println();

    // Obtain the Authorization URL
    System.out.println("Fetching the Authorization URL...");
    final String authorizationUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl();
    System.out.println("Got the Authorization URL!");
    System.out.println("Now go and authorize ScribeJava here:");
    System.out.println(authorizationUrl);
    System.out.println("And paste the authorization code here");
    System.out.print(">>");
    final String code = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println();

    // Trade the Request Token and Verfier for the Access Token
    System.out.println("Trading the Request Token for an Access Token...");
    final OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = service.getAccessToken(code);
    System.out.println("Got the Access Token!");
    System.out.println("(if your curious it looks like this: " + accessToken
            + ", 'rawResponse'='" + accessToken.getRawResponse() + "')");
    System.out.println();

    // Now let's go and ask for a protected resource!
    System.out.println("Now we're going to access a protected resource...");
    final OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, PROTECTED_RESOURCE_URL);
    service.signRequest(accessToken, request);
    final Response response = service.execute(request);
    System.out.println("Got it! Lets see what we found...");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(response.getCode());
    System.out.println(response.getBody());

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Thats it man! Go and build something awesome with ScribeJava! :)");



    try {
        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(response.getBody());
        new Print(true, ""+jo.toString());
        new Print(true, "my array is: "+jo.getJSONArray("response"));
        JSONArray responce = jo.getJSONArray("response");
        new Print(true, "my id is: "+responce.getJSONObject(0).getInt("uid") );
        new Print(true, "acess token: "+accessToken.getAccessToken());

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    TransportClient transportClient = new HttpTransportClient();
    VkApiClient vk = new VkApiClient(transportClient);

    try {
        UserActor userActor = new UserActor(new JSONObject(response.getBody()).getJSONArray("response").getJSONObject(0).getInt("uid"),
                accessToken.getAccessToken());

        try {
            vk.wall().post(userActor).message("Test message").execute();
        } catch (ApiException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Что сделано не правильно? Почему возникает подобная ошибка? В scope передал необходимый запрос, токен получен, а доступа к методу нет.

Comment: а через постер можете сделать запрос с токеном?

Comment: извините, что за постер?

Comment: один из REST client

Answer (score 2):

Проблема решилась, изменив callback на https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html.

```
 final OAuth20Service service = new ServiceBuilder()
        .apiKey(clientId)
        .apiSecret(clientSecret)
        .state(secretState)
        .scope("wall,offline") // разрешения на действия со стеной и постоянный доступ
        // не работает
        //.callback("https://google.com.ua/")
        //работает
        .callback("https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html")
        .build(VkontakteApi.instance());
```

Проблема связана с тем, что для standalone приложений по умолчанию запрещено использовать некоторые методы (wall в том числе, даже если в scope запрашиваем права), если callback идет на иной адрес, чем "https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html.".

[Ссылка с подробным разъяснением данной и иных проблем](https://habrahabr.ru/post/179953/)